# datatable component re renders everytime a state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created reusable datatable component with react-data-table-component package.

```
    // these are the states I am using in the component
    // since parent component doesn't need to know about pages, total rows. I decided to 
    // define them inside the component and manage them from here. 

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(10);
    const [totalRows, setTotalRows] = useState(0);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);


    useEffect(()=>{
       ApiService.createTransaction(data).then((response)=>{
        setData(response.data)
        setTotalRows(response.recordsFiltered);
        setPage(_page);
        props.setLoading(false);
      })
    },[])
```

I am using this component this way

```
 <CustomDatatable {parameters}/>
```

Problem is, after I receive response and try to set state data, component renders each time I set any state. How can I stop re rendering. any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `useEffect` dependent on a changing variable by adding that variable to the dependency array, which is the second argument of the `useEffect`.  Like this:

```js
    useEffect(()=>{
       ApiService.createTransaction(data).then((response)=>{
        setData(response.data)
        setTotalRows(response.recordsFiltered);
        setPage(_page);
        props.setLoading(false);
      })
    },[data])
```

Now the `useEffect` only runs when `data` changes.  You can add other things in that array to give it more dependencies.

Comment: Problem is elsewhere, suppose when I update state with  setDdata, setTotalRows, setPage component re renders. I don't want dependent useEffect call

Comment: so you want to make the api call exactly once?  like on component mount?

Comment: yes, which is working fine. but component renders each time I try to update state. I would like to stop that.

Comment: like I have 3 states, so component renders 3 times with setstates

Comment: Based on what you've written, with the empty dependency array, that `useEffect` should not be running again and again with changes to your other state variables.  There must be something else going on here.